# Switch between file and playlist in jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer

If I have created a single video setup like so:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".playvideo", function() {
    vid_url = $(this).attr("href");
    jwplayer("vplayer").setup({
        file: vid_url,
        width: "80%",
        aspectratio: "16:9"
    });
});
```

I now have an RSS link, `<a href="playlist.xml">`, that I would like to pass into the same function... how do I do that? Do I have to have two click functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadVid(vid) {

    jwplayer("vplayer").load([{file: vid}]);
    }
    loadVid('playlist.xml');
```

See [this](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439570-example-loading-new-playlists)

Comment: WOW! JW Player 7! It looks as if there's more functionality in this new API.

Comment: Thanks but the player hasn't been initialised yet - there's nothing to 'load' into - there's only `<div id="vplayer"></div>` (I'm a novice with jscript so apologies if I've misunderstood the answer)

Comment: jwplayer("vplayer").setup({ Blah options}); initializes it

Comment: you can work a simple function like loadVid(); into your block.

Comment: JW7++ :-) Great stuff.

Comment: I've been staring at this for ages and I'm still not sure how I would put that function inside the on click function. I've set up this jsfiddle to show a more complete version of the code (still trimmed for clarity but has more of what I am needing) http://jsfiddle.net/danielmee/4bzddfm0/ Comments show the if/else idea I was playing with. Just wondering if your answer can still work in this example, just so I know if it's me not knowing js enough or if this context matters. Appreciate your help @zer00ne

Comment: @Daniel I have opened up a chatroom. Scroll down to the bottom of this page and click the chat link. Search for "JW Player".

Comment: At a glance, here's what you need to know:      1. When using a RSS list, place the xml(or rss either extension works) file in the same directory as the html file that jw runs on.   2.  If that's not possible, then you need to use CORS or modify your .htaccess file.   3. I could fork and modify your fiddle but I don't think it'll work with how the media is located (see #1)

Comment: I tried to use search on the chat room, but I couldn't find it, so use this instead: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84398/jw-player

Comment: Hello @zer00ne - I think we're in different timezones ;) I wasn't able to get to this today (work was busy) but really appreciate the help. In the real use case the xml rss does reside on the same server - just wasn't sure how to get that to work in the jsfiddle. I am able to load a file or playlist easily and I can detect which one the vid_url var is - just can't work out how to get .setup() to switch between `playlist:` or `sources:` depending on `isitaplaylist`. I've tried usual if/else but that broke it.

Comment: @Daniel I live in California UTC -7, I reworked an old jw audio project into a video test page. It uses straight JS since JW6 doesn't work well with jQuery. Take a look here: http://arcx.s3.amazonaws.com/av/videorss.html, and copy the source. It should give you some insight and give us a mutual starting point as to what you need to know and what you don't need to know.